# Linux `file` command display encoding

Tags: linux, bash

The `file` command returns me the encoding of a file + the EOL if it's not LF.

But it returns `ASCII` for both `ANSI` and `UTF-8 without BOM`. On `UTF-8` files it returns `UTF-8 Unicode (with BOM)`.

An I doing something wrong, or it's the default behavior? At if it's the default behavior how I can see if it's ANSI or UTF-8 without BOM?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`file` tries to give you as specific information as possible (the opposite case would be to always print `binary file`, which is technically correct but not very useful). [ANSI is not a specific encoding](https://stackoverflow.com/a/700221/96588), and UTF-8 is a *superset* of ASCII, so it will report ASCII for both if the bytes contained in the file all are inside the ASCII charset.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot determine if a file is encoded in ASCII (8-bit) or ANSI or UTF-8 (without BOM). This is only a guess of `file`.

When a file has a BOM then `file` will guess that it is UTF encoded (either UTF-8 or UTF-16 or UTF-32). But without this you see only a binary stream of data which could be a text file encoded in some encoding.

I bet that `file` will also fail on determining the difference between ASCII and ISO-8859-1 because the first 128 bytes are the same in both encodings (as in ANSI).